# android-app link not working on android Ver 12

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have tried implementing app linking in android.It is working fine till android version 11.Later version is opening the app link in browser. I have followed the grilled potato salad example that is given in this link.https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

I have tried adding the line autoVerify=true in manifest activity [image: Below is the image in manifest file]

Answer (score 0):

For version 12 we have to generate assetlinks.json file by using keystore sha1256. keep that file in domain root .well-known folder for auto verification

-- for more info see App Links Assistant under Tools in android studio